# deleting a project; not in bulk deletion or ghost listings

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I'm running into an issue where sonar analysis is failing where one of the modules (a framework) of an existing project'X' is

> already defined in SonarQube but not as a module of project X, please delete it from SonarQube and then relaunch the analysis of project X.

In SQ, the framework module that is creating the error can be found in the listing of Project Permissions, however it is not listed on the Project Deletion page, nor is it listed as a ghost project.

Any suggestions for deleting this *project* or a workaround?

Comment: hi man. Did you try to restart your sonarqube instance?

Comment: yes, no luck.  Also, I tried to add the name/key to provision the project, just to see if I could delete it, it seems to already exist.  however, it is not listed as a provisioned project.  At one time I was having difficulty getting the project scanned and may have (probably) tried to add the module as a project.